# How to avoid repeating docstring and parameters for Python subclasses?

Tags: python, oop, subclassing

Consider the following example:

```
class A:
    """
    Simple
    :param a: parameter a explained
    """
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """
        More complicated
        :param a: parameter a explained.  <- repetition here
        :param b: parameter b explained.
        """
        super().__init__(a)  # this call will have to change if `A()` does
        self._b = b


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, c, **kwargs):
        """
        More complicated without repetition of documentation
        :param c: parameter c explained.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._c = c
```

What I often find myself doing when sub-classing, is what happens for `B`: repeating the documentation for `A` (its superclass).

The reason I do is because if you don't, like for `C`, IDEs and documentation tools can't resolve the full signature of the constructor and will only provide hints for the new functionality, hiding the documentation of the super class that still applies, even though it works as expected.

To avoid having to repeat like in `B`, what is the best practice in Python to create a sub-class for some other class, adding a parameter to the constructor, without having to repeat the entire documentation of the superclass in the subclass?

In other words: **how can I write class `B` so that parameter hints in IDEs allow users of the class to see that it takes `a` and `b` as a parameter, without specifying all the other parameters besides the new `b` again?**

In this case, it doesn't matter all that much of course, although even here, if the signature of `A`s constructor changes later, the documentation for `B` will have to be updates as well. But for more complex classes with more parameters, the problem becomes more serious.

Additionally, if the signature of `A` changes, the call to `super().__init__()` in `B`s constructor will have to change as well, while `C` keeps working as long as there are no conflicts (i.e. `A`s new parameter on the constructor is not also called `c`).

Comment: Not really sure if [answers in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100166/inheriting-methods-docstrings-in-python) will actually help your IDE usage, but in short Python was never designed to have this capability, but it may be emulated using methods in that thread, either the decorator or the metaclass.

Comment: @metatoaster I suppose that does provide an answer to the docstring part of my question, do you have any ideas on avoiding the impact to the call to super? I.e. having to repeat the entire signature in the subclass constructor?

Comment: Short of changing how the bytecode gets generated from the input source (such that the code executed by call to `super` is folded/duplicated into the current function), no. Alternative methods: you may try to create a metaclass of some kind that will manipulate all input callables such that they will have the correct `__doc__` (but this does not solve the IDE issue), or via some kind of code template generation. As Python IDEs tend to rely on the static entries inside the source files as again, Python has no innate concept of docstring inheritance (though docgen tools like sphinx emulates it).

Comment: An even earlier [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025562/inherit-docstrings-in-python-class-inheritance) in which one of the later answers introduced the [`custom_inherit`](https://github.com/rsokl/custom_inherit) package which may or may not satisfy your use case.