# Any way to get "interfaces" with Cython?

Tags: python, cython

My application needs to have several Cython `cdef` classes that inherit from a single base class, but yet still implement many interfaces. These interfaces would be used to do `isinstance()` checks on the classes to make sure they conform to certain interfaces.

I know Cython doesn't support multiple inheritance, but is there any way at all to implement interface-like behavior. It seems like a rather glaring limitation in Cython and I'm sure I'm not the only person to encounter this problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of such interfaces in your Python code?  Normally people start with Python code and port performance critical parts to `cython`.  Or use `cython` as glue between Python code and `c` or `c++` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it exactly as you would in pure Python when faced with a base class that you can't change but that you want to associate with an interface: you use the [abstract base classes module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

There's two options to chose from:

1. you either `register` your class as belonging to an interface ("abstract base class") like I've done for `InterfaceA`, or
2. you give your interface a `__subclasshook__` that allows it to claim any class with the right methods like I've done for `InterfaceB`.

Example:

```
import abc

# define the interfaces as normal (non-Cython) Python classes
class InterfaceA(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    # Python3 syntax. metaclasses are slightly different in python2   
    pass

class InterfaceB(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def useful_function(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls,other_cls):
        if cls is InterfaceB:
            if any("useful_function" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented


# our Cython class
cdef class C:
    def useful_function(self):
        return 1

c = C()

print(isinstance(c,InterfaceA)) # prints False
InterfaceA.register(C)
print(isinstance(c,InterfaceA)) # prints True
print(isinstance(c,InterfaceB)) # prints True
```

Comment: Ah, I see, we're bailing out into pure python to do our inheritance. That works, and it's a bit more elegant than the hack I was thinking up.

Comment: It's not quite that: `class C` is still a Cython class and doesn't inherit from classes `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`. However `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` use pure Python to modify the behaviour of `isinstance` when it's called on them.

Comment: See also this excellent answer, which also mentions multiple inheritance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392406/1959808