# How can I detect a list of lists, of tuples or of non-string sequences in general?

Tags: python, list, tuples, sequence

I have a `list`, and I would like to boolean test whether the `list` contains any of: `list`s or `tuple`s or non-string `sequence`s or `list`-like objects.

I would like the test return `False` if the `list` is of `str`s or any other unspecified iterable.

How can I evaluate this efficiently (lazily) in python?

Should I, for example use `isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)` together with a list comprehension condition?

Or could I collapse the elements of the `list` and test for residuals?

Here's how it goes:

{`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`} are {`str`s, `int`s, `UUID`s, ...}

```py
x1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
x2 = [(a, b),(c, d),(e, f)]
x2 = [[a, b],[c, d],[e, f]]

result = dict(x1=False, x2=True, x3=True)

def func(y):
    ...
    return z

for x in [x1, x2, x3]:
    assert func(x) == result[x], "Function needs an answer!"
```

What is a good way to populate `func`?

PS: Here is an example of a relevant list-like object (type `OmegaConf.ListConfig`):

https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/blob/a68b149b8e1a9e9a0cabc83e8691df8c6620909a/omegaconf/listconfig.py#L42C1-L43C1

Comment: Well, does `isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)` correctly match your desired values and _not_ match your undesired values…?

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension. Use the `any()` or `all()` function with a generator, depending on what you want to test. They're both lazy, they stop as soon as they've determined the answer.

Comment: WHy don't you give some detail about your actual issue and what types exactly you want matched and which you don't.  Like some sample input and output.

Comment: Thanks for all helpful feedback - I will address these shortly

Comment: While you are at it, what constitutes  a list-like object to you?

Comment: @deceze cc Barmar cc user2390182 Added significant detail as requested with many thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to exclude `str` (and likely `bytes`) from the sequence-like objects:

```
from typing import Sequence

# type test single item
def is_seq_but_not_str(item):
    return isinstance(item, Sequence) and not isinstance(item, (str, bytes))

# test list if any item passes test
def func(y):
    return any(map(is_seq_but_not_str, y))
```

The [sequence protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566044/what-is-pythons-sequence-protocol) itself is not a 100% well defined, but most sources cite the presence of some of `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__reversed__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__` (by my subjective order of relevance; notice that the latter three can be implemented by means of the first two). Testing e.g. only for the first two will include `dict` which is explicitly *not* a sequence.
If tested very strictly, `__getitem__` should raise an `IndexError` for any item (`not 0 <= item < len(seq)`) and a `TypeError` for non-`int` items. In contrast, mappings (like `dict`) just raise a  `KeyError` for any non-member item.

So, for custom classes that don't inherit from `Sequence` (or [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392352/python-abcs-registering-vs-subclassing) with it), such a test could look like:

```
def custom_is_seq_but_not_str(item, 
                              required=("__len__", "__getitem__", "__reversed__")):
    if isinstance(item, (str, bytes)):
        return False
    return all(hasattr(item, attr) for attr in required)
    # or a little stronger
    # return all(callable(getattr(item, attr, None)) for attr in required)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> a = ['a', 1, [2,4]]
>>> any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), a))
True
>>> any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a))
True
>>> any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), a))
True
>>> any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), a))
False
```